# Merging issue in two xml documents using XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

The existing XML file(test.xml) content is as under

```
<manifest xmlns:imsmd="http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM">
<resources>
<resource>
<file href="default.xml">
<metadata>
<imsmd:lom />
</metadata>
</file>
</resource>
</resources>
</manifest>
```

What I need is to add new node so that the final output resembles:

```
<manifest xmlns:imsmd="http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM">
<resources>
<resource>
<file href="default.xml">
<metadata>
<imsmd:lom />
</metadata>
</file>

<file href="testimg.png">
<metadata>
<imsmd:lom />
</metadata>
</file>
</resource>
</resources>
</manifest>
```

My try so far (though not entirely correct is as under)

```
XNamespace ns = @"http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM";
            XNamespace lomns = ":lom";


            var doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\test.xml");

            var result = new XDocument(
                new XElement(ns + "manifest",                   
                    new XElement("file", new XAttribute("href", "testimg.png"),
                    new XElement("metadata", new XElement(lomns + "imsmd"))

                     )
                 )
             );

            //merge
            doc.Root.Add(result.Root.Elements());
```

whose output is

```
<manifest xmlns:imsmd="http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM">
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <file href="default.xml">
        <metadata>
          <imsmd:lom />
        </metadata>
      </file>
    </resource>
  </resources>
  <file href="testimg.png">
    <metadata>
      <imsmd xmlns=":lom" />
    </metadata>
  </file>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is adding new element to the root, but as per your required output you mentioned a new element(`file`) should be `resource`.

Locate the element `resource` in your `xml` and then add the element.

```
 doc.Descendants("resource")
    .ElementAt(0)
    .Add(new XElement("file", new XAttribute("href", "testimg.png"),
         new XElement("metadata", new XElement(doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("imsmd")+ "lom"))));
```

**Output:**

```
 <manifest xmlns:imsmd="http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM">
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <file href="default.xml">
        <metadata>
          <imsmd:lom />
        </metadata>
      </file>
      <file href="testimg.png">
        <metadata>
          <imsmd:lom />
        </metadata>
      </file>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</manifest>
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wdRHlR)

Comment: it's correct but only a small issue instead of  <imsmd xmlns=":lom" />, I am looking for <imsmd:lom />. How to resolve that ?